# Lowercase in acronym

Tags: glossaries

I have set like this:

```
% Acronym in French and in English

\newacronym{ser}{SER}{Surface équivalente Radar ou \emph{Radar Cross Section} }

% In the text
abc \acrfull{ser} xyz

% In PDF
abs Surface équivalente Radar ou Radar Cross Section xyz
```

I would like the full name appeared lowercase for the first letter, but it should be still uppercase in the glossary.

Thank for your help !

Comment: your code is not compileable!